# Retrieve data from a table and from a dropdown list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have three elements with some attributes, in my example it will be a price and these elements will be fruits, all these elements were manually added with their belonging price. 
On another side, I put a Dropdown list, this list is in fact all elements of the table's column named "Fruits", what I would like to do is to find the price that belong to the selected fruit, this mean here, the right column of the column selected for the dropdown list.

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSnY.png)

```
Fruits  Price               
Apple   4           Selected fruit  Price found :
Orange  2           Orange     ↓   FORMULA ????
Banana  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vlookup:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,A2:B4,2,FALSE),"")
```

A2:B4 is the table Fruits Price starting in Apple as in your picture
C3 is where your choice from DropDown List of selected fruit
2 correspond to the second column B for prices
Vlookup will look for C3 in column A when the exact match (False) is found it will return the value from column B same row
Iferror will return empty "" you can change it to 0 when no match if any.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it in the following way:
C2 contains a combobox that is using "$A$2:$A$4" as input range and "$C$3" as cell link. I than added "=INDIRECT("a"&C3+1)" to D2 and "=INDIRECT("b"&C3+1)" to E2.

[image]